# Georgia absentee request data 2022 general election?

Tags: united-states, vote-by-mail, georgia

Absentee ballot requests began in Georgia on August 22. Is there currently publicly available data on how many Georgia voters requested absentee ballots and if so can it be broken down by county?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly (to me), yes - this information is already available.  You can download the CSV files [from this page](https://sos.ga.gov/page/voter-absentee-files), and each numbered spreadsheet within the zip file appears to correspond to a county.  There's also a combined "statewide" file in there.
<sub>*Note that as of right this moment (8/25 at 6:29 PM), the data is from yesterday at 6:17 PM, so it may refresh daily.*</sub>

Based on this data and an automated count I ran, the top five counties are currently:

| County Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| COBB | 7478 |
| DEKALB | 6976 |
| FULTON | 5801 |
| GWINNETT | 4440 |
| CHATHAM | 2946 |

And there are 75,992 total applications in the state.

Comment: The next data refresh after the one I used was from 9:16 PM on the 25th.  I'm not updating this post to take it into account, but it does show that it's updating roughly daily.